# Corolla 2009: I would like to fix my front spoiler myself

Tags: corolla, body-work

I am posting pictures of my front spoiler. Can any of you instruct me on how to fix this, or whether it cannot be fixed and needs to be replaced? I am not very handy, and have never fixed any parts of a car, but I am very good at following directions, can be very patient, and don't want to shell 300 bucks to replace this, which seems a minor issue.
Thanks.[image: spoiler loose]

Comment: We would really need some better pictures to understand what is going on and give you some instruction. Can you take several and post them up by editing your question? It would be a great assistance in helping you.

Comment: Sorry, the other ones I took are too big and they won't upload. I will try again tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That should be pretty simple.  You should try to (carefully) remove the whole piece of flare and you will notice it is attached to the body via small plastic clips that look like this:

[image]

They are called **fender clips** and are probably best ordered on eBay.  You insert them in the sockets on the body side and then click the flare over them sort of like clothing snap-on buttons.

Now this is strongly dependent on both the body and flare not being mangled.  I was unable to have clips reliably hold my fender flare because the fender (metal part integral to my truck) was bent out of shape as a result of an accident (as can be seen from the uneven surface around both clips in the picture) so I had to use sheetmetal screws but I made it look cool.  I hope you won't have the same problem.